# stacked bar chart shows hanging zeros when all values are 0 highcharts

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I am using stacked bar high charts. Its showing hanging 0 when all of the data is zero but  when at least one of them have proper value it shows 0 sticked to y axis. I want this should be applicable also when entire data is 0 please refer 
    http://jsfiddle.net/rutup/6hxPU/8/

```
 function createBarChart(source, title, placeHolderId, sideText, xColumnValue) {


$('#' + placeHolderId).highcharts({
    credits: { enabled: false },
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    exporting: { enabled: false },
    title: {
        text: false
    },

    xAxis: {
        categories: xColumnValue
    },

    legend: {
        layout: 'vertical',
        align: 'right',
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        y:20,
        borderWidth: 0
    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        //type: 'logarithmic',
        //tickInterval:
        lineWidth: 0,
        gridLineWidth: 0,
        title: {
            text: sideText
        },
        labels: {
            enabled: false
        },
        stackLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            style: {
                fontWeight: 'bold',
                color: 'gray'
            }
            , formatter: function () {
                return calcTotalAntiLog2(this);
            }
        }
    },
    tooltip: {
        formatter: function () {
            return '<b>' + this.x + '</b><br/>' +
                this.series.name + ': ' + calcAntiLog(this.y) //+ '<br/>' +//calcAntiLog(this.y)
            // 'Total: ' + calcAntiLog(this.point.stackTotal);//calcAntiLog(this.point.stackTotal)
        }
    },
    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            stacking: 'normal',
            dataLabels: {
                color: 'white',
                enabled: true,
                formatter: function () {
                    return calcAntiLog(this.y);
                }
            }
        }
    },
    series: source
});
```

}

Comment: But what is wrong with this example: http://jsfiddle.net/6hxPU/9/ ? You have all 0-values, so nothing is displayed..

Comment: @PawełFus its correct but i want  to show total as 0   http://jsfiddle.net/rutup/6hxPU/12/

Comment: I changed your value to null, like others and still fine: http://jsfiddle.net/6hxPU/13/

Comment: it shows hanging 0 i want this 0 to be stuck to x axis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply set `minRange` for yAxis. For example: http://jsfiddle.net/6hxPU/14/

Comment: Great @Pawl it also worked i was looking for changing veritcal align conditionaly.but do you think it will work with decimal values also

Comment: What do you mean to change vertical align conditionally?  Yes, it will work with decimals too - just set lower minRange, like 0.0000001.

Comment: I mean  stackLabels: {
                            
                verticalAlign: 'bottom'
            }

Comment: But this isn't problem with verticalAlign. If you have all null values, Highcharts can't calculate extremes on yAxis (since it's just not possible) - 0 (or closest to 0) value is in the middle. When providing directly minRange will force Highcharts to display 0-value on a bottom of a chart.